# How to get the difference between two dates in years, months and days?

Tags: extract, firebird

I have 2 date values in my FB3 table.

```
STARTDATE = 09/01/2021
ENDDATE =   05/01/2023
```

I need to get difference between the 2 dates as YEAR, MONTH, DAY
According to above dates, the result = YEAR = 1, MONTH = 8, DAYS = 0

I tried

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ENDDATE-STARTDATE),
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ENDDATE-STARTDATE),
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM ENDDATE-STARTDATE),
```

but I get the error message:

> Specified EXTRACT part does not exist in input datatype

How can I do it?

Comment: What is the result for: `SELECT STARTDATE`?   It might just be: `0.00445324`, which is 9 divided by 1 divided by 2021, or you do get `08/01/2021'`, which might be a string, but is not a date value ....   First you need to make sure that STARTDATE (and ENDDATE) do contain a DATE, an not something else.

Comment: Thank you Luuk,  SELECT STARTDATE returns 09/01/2021 as DATE same for ENDDATE

Comment: then you might need: [DATEDIFF](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html)

Comment: That's why the have DOCS for DATABASES........   

Comment: The expression `ENDDATE-STARTDATE` is not a date, time or a timestamp type, so extract won't work.

Comment: @Luuk You link to the Firebird 2.1 Language Reference Update, the 'better' link is the Firebird 3.0 Language Reference: [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-datediff)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `ENDDATE-STARTDATE` is not a date, time or a timestamp type, it is an `INTEGER` with the number of days between the dates, so [`EXTRACT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-extract) won't work. Firebird does not have an `INTERVAL` datatype, like some other DBMSes have.

As [Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039/luuk) mentioned in the comments, you could use [`DATEDIFF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-datediff). However, doing so will not have the desired effect, because `DATEDIFF` will take the difference between the current unit, ignoring 'lower' units, and it will take all units, so the result would by 2 years (2023-2021 = 2), 20 months (total number of months between September 2021 and May 2023 and 607 days (total number of days between 1 Sept 2021 and 1 May 2023).

There is no built-in way to get the difference you want. You would need to find a custom UDF or UDR that does this, or write your own UDF, UDR or PSQL function or procedure.

For example, something like:

```sql
create procedure custom_diff(startdate date, enddate date)
    returns (years integer, months integer, days integer)
as
    declare calcdate date;
begin
    if (startdate > enddate) then
    begin
        calcdate = enddate;
        enddate = startdate;
        startdate = calcdate;
    end
    else
    begin
        calcdate = startdate;
    end
    
    years = datediff(year, calcdate, enddate);
    calcdate = dateadd(year, years, calcdate);
    if (calcdate > enddate) then
    begin
        years = years - 1;
        calcdate = dateadd(year, -1, calcdate);
    end
    
    months = datediff(month, calcdate, enddate);
    calcdate = dateadd(month, months, calcdate);
    if (calcdate > enddate) then
    begin
        months = months - 1;
        calcdate = dateadd(month, -1, calcdate);
    end
    
    days = datediff(day, calcdate, enddate);
    
    suspend;
end
```

Which you can then use as:

```sql
select *
from (
    select date'09/01/2021' as startdate, date'05/01/2023' as enddate 
    from rdb$database
) r
cross join custom_diff(r.startdate, r.enddate)
```

Which results in :

| STARTDATE | ENDDATE | YEARS | MONTHS | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | 2023-05-01 | 1 | 8 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are somehow complicated. A year is reliably 12 months so I would suggest this:

```
create procedure custom_diff(startdate date, enddate date)
    returns (years integer, months integer, days integer)
as
begin
  months = datediff(month, startdate, enddate);
  if (dateadd(month, months, startdate) > enddate) then
   begin
     months = months - 1;
   end
  years = months / 12;
  days = enddate - dateadd(month, months, startdate);
  months = mod(months, 12);
  suspend;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or alter procedure GET_DATE_DIFF (
    I_DATE1 date,
    I_DATE2 date)
returns (
    O_YEARS integer,
    O_MONTHS integer,
    O_DAYS integer)
as
declare variable FSELECTOR smallint;
declare variable V_DATE date;
begin
    O_YEARS = 0;
    O_MONTHS = 0;
    O_DAYS = 0;
    V_DATE = I_DATE1;
    FSELECTOR = 1;/* years */
    while (V_DATE < I_DATE2) do
    begin
        if (FSELECTOR = 1) then
            if (dateadd(year, 1, V_DATE) <= I_DATE2) then
            begin
                V_DATE = dateadd(year, 1, V_DATE);
                O_YEARS = O_YEARS + 1;
            end
            else
                FSELECTOR = FSELECTOR + 1;

        if (FSELECTOR = 2) then
            if (dateadd(month, 1, V_DATE) <= I_DATE2) then
            begin
                V_DATE = dateadd(month, 1, V_DATE);
                O_MONTHS = O_MONTHS + 1;
            end
            else
                FSELECTOR = FSELECTOR + 1;

        if (FSELECTOR = 3) then
        begin
            O_DAYS = datediff(day, V_DATE, I_DATE2);
            V_DATE = I_DATE2;
        end

    end
    suspend;
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much  user13964273,  rstrelba